# Excel Web Regional Formats

Tags: excel, regional-settings, excel-online

I want to create a Excel for Web, which changes the currency format according to the regional settings of the logged in user.

So, when user Dan with regional settings Germany is logged in he should see € as currency.
When Phill is logged in with regional settings United States he should see $ as currency.

I have already created an excel File with German regional settings.
Maybe someone can open and verify with United States Settings that the formats are changing.

[Excel File OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArELjGgAiKGcgQmE89rLymcGnCv0?e=BdlDDS)

My settings and what I see in Excel:
[image]

Comment: We did this, a long time ago, as part of the macro: a subroutine of the macro checked for all the system settings like names of months, use of , or ; and used them to open the template. You might want to do something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think that‘s not an option for me since Excel Web does not support macros as far as I know.

Comment: I've opened it in the UK with UK settings but the currency still shows as € euros and not £ pound sterling